# No response to any input in basic procedures screen of windows 10 fresh install on a positivo DUO ZX3040

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-installation, tablet, docking-station

I succeeded in using the MediaCreationTool21H1.exe to create a boot-able pen drive with **windows 10 32bits**.

After multiple attempts using other tools, because the tablet only boots up the windows installation if it is a windows 10 32 bits, and when i used Rufus to make the usb it ended in error saying it did not have enough memory to start the installation.

everything was going ok, till during the installation it locked at the basic procedures screen to select the region, it does not respond to any input, i did a fresh install using another usb stick and it locks again in the same screen.

The keyboard works on the bios and during the initial phase of the installation, and its not hard frozen because if i undock the keyboard the installation reacts going back to the previous screen and asks the keyboard layout, but nothing changes and it does not receive any input, the hard disk is a flash drive soldered on the board and the only usb port i can use is on the keyboard dock, i already tried plugging another keyboard and mouse there to no avail.

i also tried creating a unattended installation, but there is no support for a 32 bits UEFI unattended file, and the tablet does not even recognize as boot-able the installation if it is on a non UEFI format and it does not support a 64bits install as it only have 1gb of ram...

the specs of the tablet:

```
Windows 10

10.1 touchscreen 1280×800 HD

Intel Atom 1.2GHz

Intel HD Graphics integrated

RAM: 1GB

SSD: 16GB

Batery: 6000mAh
```

Comment: Check your CPU is on this list - [Windows 10 21H1 Supported Intel Processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-10-21h1-supported-intel-processors) I don't think it is, I think you have a [Z2520](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/75203/intel-atom-processor-z2520-1m-cache-1-20-ghz/specifications.html)

Comment: I checked every single version on these lists ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements ) and NONE of the versions has this processor " atom Z3735G " nonetheless it came from factory with windows 10 installed and it has OEM product keys preinstalled on UEFI so it should work anyway.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue... i had to connect an external usb keyboard and restart the tablet with the keyboard connected, it recognized the keyboard and allowed me to navigate the install procedures... and somehow after it finished the keyboard and mouse pad of the dock-station started working again... but then it started not working anymore soon after... seems i have an hardware issue at my hands...